# Restart remote service from DirectAdmin

Tags: service, restart, directadmin

I have 8 servers connected together to a kind of cluster. On one of the servers i have DirectAdmin that controll all configs (config files mounted over NFS). Everything works correct except restarting services after configs updates.
How to force service restart on all 8 servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restart services on your server you need to login it, I will suggest create bash script on your one of the server and execute it, You can setup SSH key to login your other server from you one server to others, so that your bash script will able to restart your services on all other servers.